# Forgot to list a country on the DS160

Tags: usa

There was a question of which countries have you visited in 5 years?

I added all countries except... my home country. :/ I am applying from another country (where I live). I booked an appointment and everything. Will this raise nay questions or will there be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you’re from a sanctioned country (Iran, North Korea’s, etc) then this would appear to be a simple error and one that can be easily explained away in person at the interview. Be apologetic and polite!

That said, the current (2018.12) USA administration is not acting predictably. Come back and update us on your status.

Comment: Added my country in a new DS160 and rescheduled to avoid any problems.

Comment: @visapp9 that’s the wise thing to do.